# Evaluating the Gamma function in Bessel's equation

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function, bessel-functions

I'm trying to evaluate the Gamma function in Bessel's equation for $v=1/4$.

> What is $\Gamma(m+5/4)$, or when solving, what is $\Gamma(1/4)$?

Comment: $$\Gamma\left(m+\dfrac{5}{4}\right)=(m+\dfrac{1}{4})\Gamma\left(m+\dfrac{1}{4}\right)$$

Comment: what does the Γ(m+1/4) term equal?

Comment: See general form $x\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"?  $\Gamma(1/4) \approx 3.625609909$.  It is a transcendental constant, which can be related to some others (e.g. see [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html)), but I don't think there's any expression for it that I'd call "simpler" than $\Gamma(1/4)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\Gamma\left(m+\frac{1}{4}\right)=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\prod _{k=1}^m\left(k-\frac{3}{4}\right)$$
$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$ is a remarkable constant. 
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\simeq 3.62560990822190831...$$
In the book "An Atlas of Functions",J.Spannier, K.B.Oldham, this constant is noted U and called the "ubiquitous constant". It appears throughout many relationships involving special functions. One most notable is :
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=2\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}\text{K}\left(1/2\right)}$$
where K$(x)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

An efficient iterative process to evaluate $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$ is :
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=\text{Arithmetic-Geometric Mean of }1 \text{ and }\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

The arithmetic-geometric mean of two numbers $A_0\:,\:B_0$ is approached by repeating : $A_{k+1}=(A_k+B_k)/2$ and $B_{k+1}=\sqrt{A_kB_k}$.

Comment: What is called the "common mean" in this answer is more conventionally called the "arithmetic-geometric mean", or the AGM.

Comment: Yes, "arithmetic-geometric mean" is more popular. I will change the notation in my answer. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Some properties of that value are gathered in [the associated wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function) article.